# How to increase C++ performance while processing cyrillic text files?

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, stl, c++17

I am developing a C++ program to analyze letter occurrences in Russian text. It works as planned, but its performance is really poor (to compare my other python program completes this task in nearly 10 seconds while this one in approximately 7 minutes).

So my question is how to increase performance? What should I read to develop an understanding of this issue?

Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "text.h"

int main()
{
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
Text_Container mytext("./text.txt");
mytext.initialize();
//std::wcout<< mytext.Display_text()<<std::endl;
mytext.print_dict(0);
mytext.print_dict(1);

return 0;
}
```

Class.cpp

```
void Text_Container::print_map(std::wstring_view comment, const std::map<wchar_t, wchar_t>& m)
{
    std::wcout << comment;
    for (const auto& [key, value] : m) {
        std::wcout << key << L" = " << value << L"; ";
    }
    std::wcout << L"\n";
}
void Text_Container::print_dict(int mode)
{
    if (mode == 0) {
        std::wcout << "Dictionary with no whitespaces\n";
        for (const auto& [key, value] : _dict) {
            std::wcout << L"'" << key << L"' = " << value << L";\n";
        }
        std::wcout << L"\n";
    }
    if (mode == 1) {
        std::wcout << "Dictionary with whitespaces\n";
        for (const auto& [key, value] : _dict_w) {
            std::wcout << L"'" << key << L"' = " << value << L";\n";
        }
        std::wcout << L"\n";
    }
}
void Text_Container::read_file(const char* filename)
{
    std::wifstream wif(filename);
    wif.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::empty(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>));
    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << wif.rdbuf();
    _text = wss.str();
}

void Text_Container::initialize()
{
    /// <summary>
    /// lowercase text
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mode"></param>
    std::wstring new_s;
    for (std::wstring::size_type i = 0; i < _text.size(); i++) {
        wchar_t temp = iterate_over_map(_text[i]);
        if (temp != '\1')
        {   //whitespaces
            wchar_t temp0 = iterate_over_dictionary(_text[i], 0);
            if (temp0 != '\1')
            {
                _f_w_text = _f_w_text + temp0;
            };
            //no whitespaces
            wchar_t temp1 = iterate_over_dictionary(_text[i], 1);
            if (temp1 != '\1')
            {
                _f_text = _f_text + temp1;
            };
            new_s = new_s + temp;
        };
    }
    _text = new_s;
}
//this function pring russian letters to lowercase
wchar_t Text_Container::iterate_over_map(wchar_t& temp) {
    if (temp == L'Ё' || temp == L'Э' || temp == L'ё' || temp == L'э') {
        temp = L'е';
    }
    if (temp == L'Ъ' || temp == L'ъ') {
        temp = L'ь';
    }
    for (const auto& [key, value] : _m) {
        if (temp == value) { return value; }
        else { if (temp == key) { return value; } }
    }
    return L'\1';
}
//this fucntion verifies input letter and if it's in the selected dictionary increases value by 1
wchar_t Text_Container::iterate_over_dictionary(wchar_t& temp, int mode) {
    std::map<wchar_t, int>::iterator itr;
    if (mode == 0)
    {
        for (itr = _dict_w.begin(); itr != _dict_w.end(); ++itr) {
            if (itr->first == temp) {
                itr->second++;
                return itr->first;
            }
        }
    }
    if (mode == 1)
    {
        for (itr = _dict.begin(); itr != _dict.end(); ++itr) {
            if (itr->first == temp) {
                itr->second++;
                return itr->first;
            }
        }
    }
    return L'\1';
}
```

Class.h

```
#define _SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
#include <string_view>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <codecvt>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <string_view>

class Text_Container
{
private:
    //dictionaries to filter text & also bring them to lowercase
    const std::map<wchar_t, wchar_t> _m{ {L'А', L'а'}, {L'Б', L'б'}, {L'В', L'в'},
                                            {L'Г', L'г'}, {L'Д', L'д'}, {L'Е', L'е'},
                                            {L'Ж', L'ж'}, {L'З', L'з'}, {L'И', L'и'},
                                            {L'Й', L'й'}, {L'К', L'к'}, {L'Л', L'л'},
                                            {L'М', L'м'}, {L'Н', L'н'}, {L'О', L'о'},
                                            {L'П', L'п'}, {L'Р', L'р'}, {L'С', L'с'},
                                            {L'Т', L'т'}, {L'У', L'у'}, {L'Ф', L'ф'},
                                            {L'Ч', L'ч'}, {L'Ц', L'ц'}, {L'Ш', L'ш'},
                                            {L'Щ', L'щ'}, {L'Ы', L'ы'}, {L'Ь', L'ь'},
                                            {L'Ю', L'ю'}, {L'Я', L'я'}, {L' ', L' '}, };
    /*
    std::map<wchar_t, int> _dict_w{ {L'а', 0}, {L'б', 0}, {L' ',0},}; //mode 0
    std::map<wchar_t, int> _dict{ {L'а', 0}, {L'б', 0},}; //mode 1
    */
    //mode 0
    std::map<wchar_t, int> _dict_w{ {L'а', 0}, {L'б', 0}, {L'в', 0},
                                            {L'г', 0}, {L'д', 0}, {L'е', 0},
                                            {L'ж', 0}, {L'з', 0}, {L'и', 0},
                                            {L'й', 0}, {L'к', 0}, {L'л', 0},
                                            {L'м', 0}, {L'н', 0}, {L'о', 0},
                                            {L'п', 0}, {L'р', 0}, {L'с', 0},
                                            {L'т', 0}, {L'у', 0}, {L'ф', 0},
                                            {L'ч', 0}, {L'ц', 0}, {L'ш', 0},
                                            {L'щ', 0}, {L'ы', 0}, {L'ь', 0},
                                            {L'ю', 0}, {L'я', 0}, {L' ', 0}, };

    //mode 1
    std::map<wchar_t, int> _dict{ {L'а', 0}, {L'б', 0}, {L'в', 0},
                                            {L'г', 0}, {L'д', 0}, {L'е', 0},
                                            {L'ж', 0}, {L'з', 0}, {L'и', 0},
                                            {L'й', 0}, {L'к', 0}, {L'л', 0},
                                            {L'м', 0}, {L'н', 0}, {L'о', 0},
                                            {L'п', 0}, {L'р', 0}, {L'с', 0},
                                            {L'т', 0}, {L'у', 0}, {L'ф', 0},
                                            {L'ч', 0}, {L'ц', 0}, {L'ш', 0},
                                            {L'щ', 0}, {L'ы', 0}, {L'ь', 0},
                                            {L'ю', 0}, {L'я', 0}, };
    //vars
    std::wstring _text = L""; // inintial text
    std::wstring _f_text = L""; //mode 1
    std::wstring _f_w_text = L"";// mode 0
    //methods
    wchar_t iterate_over_map(wchar_t& temp);
    wchar_t iterate_over_dictionary(wchar_t& temp, int mode);
public:
    //constructor
    Text_Container(const char* filename) { read_file(filename); };
    //destructor

    //methods
    std::wstring Display_text() { return _text; }
    std::map<wchar_t, wchar_t> give_m() { return _m; };

    void print_map(std::wstring_view comment, const std::map<wchar_t, wchar_t>& m);
    void read_file(const char* filename);
    void print_dict(int mode);
    void initialize();
};
```

Comment: Maybe the good decision would be to shift from UTF to Windows-1251?

Comment: You should stick to Unicode. It takes no time to read the extra byte. Which part of your code is slow, or you think it's slow?

Comment: Are you measuring the performance of a debug build, by any chance?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I was, but I created a release build and the result is still horrible.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I mean it might be easier to get rid of wstring wchar stuff because it seems to me that those and STL are poorly compatible.

Comment: @walltime *I was, but I created a release build* -- Please update your post with those times, and not the timing tests for a debug build.  If the timings you are showing are for a release build, please update your post to state *clearly* this information.  Otherwise, anyone reading your question has to scroll down to the comments to figure out if you are running a release or debug build.  Posting complete details of compiler, compiler options, etc. should not be an afterthought when posting questions concerning the speed of a C++ program.

Comment: Note: `imbue()` on a file will not always work after it has been opened. You need to create the object. Then call imbue() then open the file.

Comment: `string` and `wstring` are derived from the same base class, they are basically the same as far as the library sees it. With `string` you might notice a marginal improvement for a very large for, it's not worth switching to outdated code page. You might have a bottle neck somewhere in your program, I don't know where it is.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the code "works", the question is just about boosting its performance, so I would suggest asking on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few areas to investigate for slowness. Starting from biggest to slowest.

Do you need to iterate over the maps instead of using at/get? This can result in a huge performance boost

```
for (itr = _dict_w.begin(); itr != _dict_w.end(); ++itr) {
            if (itr->first == temp) {
                itr->second++;
                return itr->first;
            }
        }
```

As well as:

```
wchar_t Text_Container::iterate_over_map(wchar_t& temp) {
    if (temp == L'Ё' || temp == L'Э' || temp == L'ё' || temp == L'э') {
        temp = L'е';
    }
    if (temp == L'Ъ' || temp == L'ъ') {
        temp = L'ь';
    }
    for (const auto& [key, value] : _m) {
        if (temp == value) { return value; }
        else { if (temp == key) { return value; } }
    }
    return L'\1';
}
```

Lets talk templates/datatypes, are maps required all your datasets?

- Can try using enums.

It could significantly help this section here. Especially if you incorporate some bitmasking

```
if (temp == L'Ё' || temp == L'Э' || temp == L'ё' || temp == L'э') {
    temp = L'е';
}
if (temp == L'Ъ' || temp == L'ъ') {
    temp = L'ь';
}
for (const auto& [key, value] : _m) {
    if (temp == value) { return value; }
    else { if (temp == key) { return value; } }
}
return L'\1';
```

It may be insightful if you could log the time it takes for certain functions/processes.

- How long does it take to read a single char?
- How long does it take to read X chars?

Some questions to consider:

- What is your RAM looking like?
- How big are the files you are reading?

  - Would it help to slice them up?
- Passing by value vs passing by reference/pointer

  - Passing by reference and setting function returns to void may help.

Lastly, I want to say that I'm not an expert at this either. So I'm interested in seeing what others have to say.

Answer (score 0):

Well this looks like a very expensive operation.

```
std::wstringstream wss;
wss << wif.rdbuf();
_text = wss.str();
```

You read the while file into a string stream `wss` (so that is one huge copy). If the file is large the internal buffer may be extended multiple times each forcing a copy of the string to a new location.

Then once you have build the stream you copy it into a string `_text`. So that is another huge copy.

Does not look like any of this is needed. Simply read from `wif` rather than from `_text`.

Answer (score 0):

i have stuff like this done but with words.

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <execution>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <atomic>


void brough(void *w);

std::vector<std::pair<std::string,int>> tfinal;

std::weak_ptr<std::atomic_int> com_r;
std::condition_variable com_cvp;
std::atomic<bool> com_tr, com_onemore;
std::mutex com_mx;
std::thread h, dest;

int instore;

int main() 
{
    std::mutex com_mp;
    std::thread h = std::thread(&brough, (void *)nullptr);

    do
    {
        instore = com_r.lock() ? (int)*com_r.lock() : instore;
        com_onemore = false;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(com_mp);
        std::string rend(instore , 'x');
        rend = rend + '\r';
        std::cout << rend << std::flush;
        com_cvp.wait_for(lk ,std::chrono::milliseconds(900) ,[] { return com_tr == !false||com_onemore == !false; }); 
    }while(!com_tr);

    h.join();
}


void brough(void *w)
{
    std::filesystem::path tf("b.txt");
    std::ifstream b(tf);
    std::shared_ptr<std::atomic_int> sp_tray = std::shared_ptr<std::atomic_int>(new std::atomic_int(0));
    std::vector<std::string> c;

    com_r = sp_tray;
    do{
        b >> *c.insert(c.end(),"");
    }while (!b.eof());

    auto t1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::vector<std::string> t;

    int counter = 0; //with the stuff below final result will be 25.0 vs 24.947 now
    //std::atomic_int int counter = 0;

    for(int ft = 0 ; ft < 15; ft++)
    {
        std::mutex mtb;
        std::string torque;
        int rd = 0;
        std::for_each(std::execution::par, c.begin(), c.end(), [&](auto a){ int wr = std::count(t.begin(), t.end(), a) == 0 ? std::count( c.begin(), c.end(), a) : 0;
        *sp_tray = 25*++counter/(15*c.size()); std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lb(mtb);  torque = wr > rd ? a : torque; rd = std::max(rd , wr); });
        t.insert(t.end(), torque);
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lt(com_mx);
        tfinal.insert(tfinal.end(), { torque , rd } );
        com_onemore = !false;
        com_cvp.notify_one();
    }
    std::cout << std::endl; 
    for(auto k : t)
        std::cout  << k << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl << "sp_tray = " <<  25.0*counter/(15*c.size()) << std::endl;
    auto t2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::milliseconds f =  std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1);
    std::cout  << f.count() << std::endl;
    
    com_tr = !false;
    com_cvp.notify_one();

}
```

it has progress bar and perf test

makefile:

```
CC = c++ -c
CFLAGS = -std=c++17 -O3
LINKER = c++
GUILIBS = -ltbb -lpthread

t: f.o
    $(LINKER) $(LFLAGS)  f.o  $(GUILIBS) -o t

f.o: f.cpp
    $(CC) $CFLAGS() f.cpp
```